# Планировщик заданий в Windows. Задачу можно создать на любое событие?

Tags: windows, планировщик-задач

Вот есть планировщик заданий. В нем можно создать задание на событие. А это событие может быть любым? Могу ли я создать задание, начинающееся при открытии какой-нибудь программы или при нажатии какой-то кнопки в окне какой-то программы?

Comment: Какая сила заставляет вас задавать этот вопрос в интернете вместо того, чтобы просто взять и попробовать?

Comment: Так я не знаю, как создавть триггеры на такие события.

Comment: Блин, там столько всяких триггеров, что фиг поймешь что к чему относится. Нагуглил, что можно как-то запуск программы использовать как триггер, но только если эта программа от самого майкрософта. Нажатие кнопки в окне программы вряд ли.

Comment: > фиг поймешь что к чему относится - а по мне так наоборот это вообще не вызывает проблем. >Нагуглил, что можно как-то запуск программы использовать как триггер, но только если эта программа от самого майкрософта. - не дадите ссылку хотя бы на это? А то у меня всякая ерунда всплывает.

Comment: вот пишут, что вроде можно https://superuser.com/questions/745318/how-to-start-a-program-when-another-one-is-started

Comment: Любое, которое записывается в журнал событий. Соответственно, ничего не мешает настроить аудит, чтобы запуск приложений записывался в журнал.

Comment: Не подскажите, где про это читануть?